# set .symtab address and flags in elf to load it into memory with arm-none-eabi toolchain

Tags: gcc, ld, cortex-m, linker-scripts, newlib

I would like to load `.symtab` into memory with gdb debugger.

At most two steps are required for a normal section (for some section, e.g. `.text`, `.data`, ... , step 1 can be skipped cause is automatically set by ld):

**1 - Set the Alloc flag (in case of a special section) to the section in the ELF. This can be done in this way for a normal section.**

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --set-section-flags .sectionName=alloc src.elf dst.elf
```

**2 - Set the address to the section. This can be done in 2 ways for a normal section AFAIK**

A - Specifying the section memory area in the LD script e.g. for text section:

```
.text :
{
    *(.text)
    *(.text*)
} > FLASH
```

B - Using again objcopy

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --change-section-address .sectioName=0x0ABCD src.elf dst.elf
```

since `.symtab` is generated automatically by the linker I cannot treat it as a normal section so none of the steps above works.

**Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?**

I already successfully implemented a workaround that to generate a new elf stripping all unneeded sections, and this works but then you have to load two elfs and i'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your end game seems wrong.  You have an arm-none compiler which implies no OS.  You need a gdbserver port to run on the ARM and use remote debug on another development PC.  You can use [seperate debug info](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html); otherwise what you are doing implies you are porting GDB to some unknown/baremetal system?  Some more info/clarification would be helpful.

Comment: I want to have available at run time the symbol table to solve symbols of other elfs